# Is it possible to migrate keyboard shortcuts for all my applications via an export?

Tags: keyboard, keynote

I have a bunch of keyboard shortcuts setup for Pages, Keynote, and several other programs. Is there a way to export and then import these shortcuts? I just reformatted my home computer and am now going through the painful process of re-creating all the shortcuts.

Paul Irish's dotfiles got me thinking about this: https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles

Comment: Could you explain why Paul Irish's dotfiles made you think about that or pinpoint the actual code you are referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you have defined the shortcut keys. The files responsible for storing these preferences are in the usual place: ~/Library/Preferences

You could simply move the files that store the preferences over to the new Mac:

- com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
- com.apple.universalaccess.plist
- com.apple.iWork.Keynote.plist
- com.apple.iWork.Pages.plist

If you were good at parsing JSON or XML, you could do the export to a text file as well using [the `plutil` tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/plutil.1.html).

Comment: I've defined the shortcuts via the System Preferences > Keyboard panel. Should/can I do this via a text editor? That'd be better for sure.

Comment: The big thing is that application shortcuts go into the app preference file and system wide ones, the system pref file. You can use `PlistBuddy` and `plutil` to systematically convert a text file into property list additions as well as to issue `defaults write` commands to append them. This is advanced scripting, but doable for a DIY hacker.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcuts for sandboxed applications are stored in `~/Library/Containers/*/Data/Library/Preferences/*.plist`. The shortcuts for all applications are in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`. You could probably just copy the preference files from the old account.

I use a shell script like this to configure the shortcuts in the [old-style property list format](http://lri.me/keybindings.html). You can print the current settings with `defaults read`.

```
defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents '{
"Back" = "@\UF702";
"Go Back" = "@\UF702";
"Forward" = "@\UF703";
"Go Forward" = "@\UF703";
"Minimize" = "\0";
}'

defaults write com.apple.finder NSUserKeyEquivalents '{
"Show Package Contents" = "@\r";
}'
```

Comment: Note that `defaults read` will return escaped `"\\"`s in shortcuts (e.g. `defaults read com.apple.finder NSUserKeyEquivalents` after the above command will return `…"@\\r"…`). Because `defaults write` automatically escapes `"\"`, the doubled `"\\"`s from the `defaults read` output will have to be cut down to the single `"\"`s seen in the above examples before you can reapply them (e.g. on your new computer) with `defaults write`

Answer (score -2):

The above answer is too complicated.  With Keynote 9 (v 5.3) and Mountain Lion, and assuming that the format bar is visible, you can simply define a key in Keyboard Shortcuts panel of the Keyboard System Preference:

1. Select "Application Shortcuts", and click the + icon
2. Select the Keynote application.
3. For the Menu Title type the font name exactly as it appears in the format bar.  I entered "Times New Roman".
4. Type the shortcut key (I used <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
5. Quit Keynote and restart it.
6. Select some text and type the shortcut key.  The font will change to Times New Roman.

Comment: How does this at all answer the OP's question about exporting and importing a set of all shortcuts for "several programs". I think you didn't fully read or understand the question.